# SSE/AVX: using float shuffles + casts as substitute for missing integer shuffle intrinsics?

Tags: x86, sse, avx

Is it always ok to simply use float shuffles + casts as substitute for missing integer shuffle intrinsics in SSE/AVX, like this:

```
__m128i x = _mm_castps_si128( _mm_shuffle_ps ( _mm_castsi128_ps(y), ...
```

In theory this should, of course, work with instructiuons that do not interpret the binary bit patterns of the vector elements and thus agnostic wrt. they contain floats or integers.
However, I remember one post by (IIRC) @Peter Cordes who wrote that using float shuffles for integer registers works on "some" CPUs only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It always works for correctness, the only risk is a cycle of extra latency on some CPUs**, notably Nehalem where bypass-latency penalties are 2 cycles each way.  It's fully fine on Sandybridge-family, no extra latency to forward to or from the shuffle unit for FP or SIMD-integer domains.  Agner Fog mentions this in his microarch guide (https://agner.org/optimize/).

[SSE: shuffle (permutevar) 4x32 integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56033329/sse-shuffle-permutevar-4x32-integers) also discusses this.

*[Fastest way to do horizontal SSE vector sum (or other reduction)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6996764)* re: shuffle performance details on old CPUs, and some mention of bypass delays (e.g. `shufps` on Core 2 runs in the integer domain, so actually has extra bypass latency when used between FP instructions.)

[implications of using _mm_shuffle_ps on integer vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26983569/implications-of-using-mm-shuffle-ps-on-integer-vector) also has some links to bypass-delay details.

You can sometimes take advantage of `psllq` or `psrlq` 64-bit shifts to move around 32-bit floats within 64-bit chunks to set up for a blend, if you're bottlenecked on shuffle-unit throughput.  But that typically does have a cycle of bypass latency if the input is coming directly from an FP math instruction.